# fix model compatibility between version 2.70 and 3.1.2

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, error, compatibility

I downloaded a model from the internet for personal use but when I opened in Blender 3.1.2 some textures are missing and I can't fix it... This model was made in 2014 with blender 2.70. Please help I tried everything I spent so many days to find something but nothing.

Blender 3.1.2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB1E2.png
Blender 2.70 https://i.stack.imgur.com/STxKY.png

Comment: Hi :). It looks like the 2.7 version is using Blender Render. That's an old engine, no longer supported. You may need to recreate the materials from scratch (should be easy tho)

Comment: Unfortunately thats not my model and I don't want to modify it without permission...
But there is nothing to patch these bugs?

Comment: You must have some tutorials on how to convert materials from Blender Render to Cycles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiZ4rBF-7yE

Comment: Hi :). This is not a bug. The old Blender Render is a completely different render engine. Either use older Blender versions, or update the materials.